# Андроид клиент для сайта на Joomla

Tags: android, joomla

Есть новостной сайт на Joomla. Хочу попробовать написать клиент Андроид приложение для вывода новостей с сайта. Есть ли какие-нибудь примеры или статьи где описывается подобное?

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего вам нужен WebView .Он покажет ваш сайт в респонсивности.
прошу  [некий туториал](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QRa4yMjoI7c)для ознакомления вообще с WevView